# Road bike identification: these lugs look familiar to anyone?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

Found this cleaning out a recently passed relative's garage. No markings or labels but looks nice. These lugs look familiar to anyone? Thanks! [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OMG. An identification question with clear photos including distinctive features! We get so many where it's just a generic BMX frame and the only photo is grainy and missing half the bike. I've no idea what bike it is but I hope somebody can help. Good luck and welcome to the site!

Comment: Crikey that's a tall bike!  I want it !

Comment: Srs question - are those 700 wheels or 650 ?

Comment: It's an old bike.  Back when stem shifters were used and all but Schwinn-class bikes were lugged.  Likely 27" (iso 630) wheels.  Note the wide flange front hub, not seen in this century.  I don't recognize the lugs, though.

Comment: A suspension seatpost is an oddball - that's newer than the rest of the bike.

Comment: You can still buy new high flange hubs if you want that retro look: 
https://velo-orange.com/collections/hubs/products/grand-cru-high-flangefront-hub

Comment: I'll note that such a tall bike is not generally "stock", and so this may very well be a custom bike.

Answer (score 5):

It's looking like a Raleigh Grand Prix. Pretty sure that lots has been changed since delivery.

The wheels are 700 and the tires are 25mm wide clinchers.

The transmission has a 7-gear stack/cassette.

I'll have to measure it but I can just straddle it at 6'1" (185 cm)

I think it is a 25" frame (63.5 cm)

Comment: I think you are right.  If you zoom in on [this one](http://user-agent.org/cgi-bin/stuff?item=2012/04/28/Bikes), you can see the same shark-fin cutouts in the lugs.